# VBA Excel date filter, multiple fileds

Tags: vba, excel, range, filtering, date-range

I'm fairly new to VBA, but learning.
I' m aiming to speed up some daily summary.

1. I got a problem with clearing the filter (in case some were put on another field) I get an error when there is none.
2. I can't get right format based on cell value, there is no error, it just select blank
3. Not sure how to select filtered range, I came up with one, but there must be a better way.

If anyone knows some good summary/tutorial how to select ranges without object Table please send me a link.

It is a part of bigger macro so declarations are made earlier, and they are working in different parts so they are not the problem.

```
Sub aktualizacja_SKU()
    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook

    var1 = DATA.Value 

    With SKU_table
        lr1 = .Range.Rows.Count
    End With
    strPath = "C:\Users\###\Desktop\###\"
    strFile = "###.xlsm"
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)

    wbTarget.Activate
```

1st problem: I tryed to find solution for error on lack of filter lines below with ' but it didn't work

```
    'Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=11, 
    '    Criteria1:="SPM"
    'Sheets("Zamówienie").ShowAllData
```

2nd one: It ignores line with filter on the date and pick a blank

```
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=4
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=4, 
    Criteria1:=Format(var1, "yyyy-mm-dd") ', Operator:=xlOr
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=11
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=11, 
    Criteria1:="SPM" ', Operator:=xlOr
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=14
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000").AutoFilter Field:=14, 
        Criteria1:="Lack of delivery"
    Sheets("Zamówienie").Select


    Range("C3:F3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    wbThis.Activate
```

3rd. I copy all range with the header then delete it, normally I would change data to a Table, but I can't change data source.

```
    SKU_table.DataBodyRange(lr1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, 
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    SKU_table.ListRows(lr1).Delete

End Sub
```

Could you please explain what new line do or send a link to the tutorial. 
I would rather understand than just copy paste.

Comment: maybe better solution of your problem is use advaced filter - you can copy results in this method in other place..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1st problem

To safely eliminate any previous filters, dont use `Worksheet.ShowAllData`; use instead `Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False`. i.e.

```
Sheets("Zamówienie").AutoFilterMode = False
```

> 2nd problem

To filter on a date, assuming your column is already formatted as date, and that `var1` is a `Date` or number variable, just use the variable, dont `Format` it. Also, you dont need two `Autofilter` statements, just one. And of course, no need to use `Select` (You dont need it and it is source of bugs).

> 3rd problem

To copy without the header, use `.Offset(1).Copy`, and there's no need to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` because the `Copy` method automatically does that.

```
Sub aktualizacja_SKU()
    Dim var1 As Date: var1 = Data.value
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\###\Desktop\###\"
    Const strFile As String = "###.xlsm"
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook: Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
    With wbTarget.Sheets("Zamówienie").Range("$A$3:$V$100000")
      .AutoFilter 11, "SPM"
      .AutoFilter 4, var1
      .AutoFilter 14, "Lack of delivery"
      .Columns("C:F").Offset(1).Copy
      SKU_table.Range(SKU_table.ListRows.Count + 2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, you cannot apply "ORed" filters on different fields. To do so you need to use a helper column, as shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201297/4926357)